# how to submit form data as "create" api method in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

in my 'category' table have some columns, for e.g title,slug,description. and i want to add items in those columns.
my api end-point looks something like this: http://localhost:8000/api/p_category/add

how to add those dynamic form data in ReactJS ?

i am probably new to reactjs. it would be great if anyone could help me out, what i am trying to solve is. thank you so much in advance.

raw data:

```
{
    "title": "",
    "slug": "",
    "description": ""
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To load data from server you should use [ajax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) request. Js has `fetch` function that allow you to make `ajax` request to server. For example, you can render your table without data and make `ajax` request in `componentDidMount` life cycle. That allow you to rerender your table after uploading data.

```
state = {
    tableData: undefined,
}

componentDidMount = () => {
    fetch(url, [options]).then(
        data => this.setState(() => ({tableData: data.data.tableData}))
    )
}

render() {
    const {tableData} = this.state;
    retrun (
        <Table><TableHeader>{tableData.map(row => <TableRow rowData={row} />)}</Table>
    )
}
```

I just wrote an example so that you can better understand the idea

Answer (score 0):

This example could help you.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Axios from 'axios';

export default class example extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            users: [],
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        Axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/')
            .then(function (response) {
                this.setState({
                    users: response.data,
                });
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }

    render() {
        const { users } = this.state;
        return users.lenght > 0 ? (
            <table striped>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td>ID</td>
                        <td>Username</td>
                        <td>Email</td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {users.map((user) => {
                        return (
                            <tr key={user.id}>
                                <td>{user.id}</td>
                                <td>{user.username}</td>
                                <td>{user.email}</td>
                            </tr>
                        );
                    })}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        ) : (
            <h1>No data available!</h1>
        );
    }
}
```